# PHP DATE/TIME Automatically inserting timezone/need to add character

Tags: php, date, time, timezone, format

Here is a piece of my code where I am attempting to return the current date/time.

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$now = date('Y-m-dTH:i:s.00+00:00');
echo $now;
?>
```

As you can see, I've added some characters at the end as well as a "T" between the day and hour.  This is to match very specific formatting that I must follow because this date will be directly transmitted to a web services that requires the data in this very specific format:

```
2014-01-31T15:05:29.04+00:00
```

As you can see, the "T" in this example stands for time.  I agree, bad choice by the web service developer, but this can not be changed.

The problem is that when PHP reads my example code, it inserts CST (the timezone) where I have my capital "T" thus causing problems because it breaks the format I am trying to achieve:

```
2014-02-03CST17:53:16.00+00:00
```

I need to be able to insert the T without the PHP function turning it into Timezone.

Any ideas?

Comment: escape the `T` with `\T`.

Comment: And don't forget to use function `gmdate()` instead of `date()`, if you wish to use fixed `+00:00` timezone offset (or set timezone to UTC).

Comment: The "T" is not a bad choice at all. That is a key element in the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.  The web service is simply using the ISO8601 Extended format with offset.  This is allowed by [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt), and used by *many* other specifications.  Get used to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned before, if you want a literal character inserted, check if it's a modifier in the format which you can find in the [PHP documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). If so, escape it.

So you basically just need to change:

```
$now = date('Y-m-dTH:i:s.00+00:00');
```

to:

```
$now = date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.00+00:00');
```